# Oops, said too much Hallel. What now?

Tags: mistakes, hallel

On *Rosh Chodesh* and on *Pesach* after the first *yom tov*, most communities recite *Hallel b'dilug* ("half" Hallel). In most *siddurim* that I'm used to, the skipped-over portions are Psalms 115:1–11 and Psalms 116:1–11.

I am looking for sources that discuss what to do if one intended to say *Hallel b'dilug* but instead did *not* skip (some of) the sections above. There are several places of realisation I've identified that may or may not make a difference as to the answer:

- Somewhere in 115:1-11 — perhaps we skip ahead to 115:12?
- Between 115:11 and 115:12 — perhaps we skip the rest of 115?
- Somewhere in 115:12–18 — perhaps we complete what we started and skip as usual in 116, or perhaps we skip the rest of 115?
- Between 115 and 116 — perhaps we have to go back and redo 115 with the proper skip, or just skip as usual in 116?
- Somewhere in 116:1–11 — perhaps we skip ahead to 116:12?
- Between 116:11 and 116:12 — perhaps we skip the rest of 116?
- Somewhere in 116:12–19 — perhaps we skip the rest of 116, or we have to redo 116 with the proper skip, or redo from 115 with the proper skips?
- After 116 — perhaps we should skip somewhere in 117—118, or perhaps we need to redo from 115 (or 116) properly?
- At the end of Hallel — perhaps we need to redo from 115 (or 116), or the entire Hallel?

If any other realisation points (or possible next steps) are worth singling out, I would be interested to hear. An ideal answer would also determine whether it makes a difference whether we're discussing an individual vs. a community, or *Hallel b'dilug* with a *bracha* vs. without a *bracha*.

Comment: IIRC half Hallel is said when it's a minhag, to show that it's a minhag and not a chovah. So maybe people that don't say a bracha on half Hallel (most sefradim, I think), which already is a sign that this is just a minhag, would have less of a reason to go back no matter what was added accidentally

Comment: For the same reason, even people who said a bracha might not go back/ skip something else if they've said one of the parts that's skipped but skipped the other (because it's still recognizably different)

Comment: These are just my own svaras though